# Number input and jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html-table, rows

I have this table:

```
<table id="product" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
   <thead>
     <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Cantidad</th>
        <th>Producto</th>
        <th>Marca</th>
        <th>Precio</th>
        <th>Importe</th>
        <th>Serial</th>
     </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

I add rows to that table with this jquery code:

```
$( "#name" ).autocomplete({
  source: 'http://sosacelulares.com/index.php/product/search',
    minLength: 1,
    select: function (event, ui) {
        var value = ui.item.value;
        var data1 = value.split("-");
        var data = data1[0].split(" ");
        $( "#product" ).show();

        var v = data[1];

        $.ajax({
           async:true,
           type: "POST",
           dataType: "html",
           contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
           url:"http://sosacelulares.com/index.php/product/get",
           data:"id="+v,
           success: function(response) {
            var returnedData = JSON.parse(response);

            $("#product > tbody").append('<tr><td>' + returnedData[0].id_product + '</td><td><input min="1" type="number" style="width: 100px;" value="" class="form-control quantity" id="quantity" placeholder="Cantidad" required></td><td>' + returnedData[0].name + '</td><td>' + returnedData[0].brand + '</td><td><input type="text" style="width: 100px;" value="' + returnedData[0].buy_price + '" class="form-control" placeholder="Precio" required></td><td></td><td><a href=""><button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Agregar Serial</button></a></td></tr>');
          }
         }); 
    },

});
```

I just look for a name in a text input and then when I find it I just add it to the table. **The problem is that the rows that I am adding they have a number input field that it is to add the quantity** I test it like this:

```
$(".quantity").change(function () {
  alert(1);
});
```

I do not know why if I change the quantity input that it is ubicated within the new row that i added with jquery it does not work, if I make a change the alert does not appear, what am I doing bad? Thanks!

Comment: use the `.on` function. `$(".quantity").on('change', function () {});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).on("change", ".quantity", function () {
  alert(1);
});
```